# Photo in job application not showing

Tags: graphics, sharelatex

I am using this template for my application, but having some trouble adding the photo "picture.png".  I then realized that within the template itself was the image also missing, could someone help find the error.

Latex code can be found here. 
https://da.sharelatex.com/project/55cde62ec94e18ad561ea6ff

Comment: I don't have access to view that. Have you actually uploaded the image to ShareLaTeX?

Comment: It should accessible public now. I haven't written in the share latex, but the source code is identical, I've used it as a template.

Comment: But the code is rather strange. It seems to be loading a package that is not present on my TeX Live 2015 system (`moderncvstylec.sty`)

Comment: hmm.. I copied the code into Texmaker and it seem to be working fine.. The only problem is the photo not appearing, I tried some other templates, but don't seem able to compile them.

Comment: @Application, which LaTeX installation? I think it is the line `\moderncvstyle{c}` that is a little problematic, because that will attempt to load `moderncvstylec.sty` which does not exist. the style is named via whole words

Comment: @daleif I think I temporarily changed it to just `c`, so you may loaded the page at just the wrong time. Now it says `casual`, and the image appears. (I'm pretty sure it didn't appear earlier though, so I'm not sure what has happened.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `\makecvtitle` after `\begin{document}`to show to photo and resume title. But notice that the coverletter is not suppose to have a photo, only the resume.